# What are the alternatives to HTML5 Canvas on the server side?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net, angular

I'm an Asp.net & C# & and Angular guy. Recently, I've been playing around with HTML5 Canvas using Konva. It is a lot of fun and I can use it to fulfil a need for certain audience. But its drawback is that it is client-based; any savvy programmer can get hold of the javascript code real fast. I want to start right and ensure that only paying customers use my app, what are your ideas?

The only thing I could come up with is to rent time slots on Virtual Machines where customers will execute a WPF or winforms executables. Or let them use a canvas javascript app on my virtual machines and maybe I'll be able to control the browser and its javascript

Please point me to where I should start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a C#/.NET developer, but I found **Blazor** quite interesting. It runs only a kind of "agent" on the client side, which sends events to the server, then all the logic runs on the server, and DOM manipulation commands are sent to the client (if I'm not wrong). The whole thing is based on C#, and it promises that you don't have to write a line of JavaScript:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor

There's a tutor on how to draw stuff with Blazor:
https://swharden.com/blog/2021-01-07-blazor-canvas-animated-graphics/

*(Disclaimer: as I said, I'm not familiar with C#)*